# Symfony2 map entity to different tables

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, mapping

I have my entity `foo` which contains the properties `id`, `bar` and `baz`. Can I populate two different tables (like `foo1` and `foo2`) with the same entity, based on the property `baz` which is not mapped. The code of the entity looks like this :

```
class foo {

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  */      
  private $id;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="string")
  */
  private $bar;

  /**
  * Property not mapped in the database
  */
  private $baz; 
}
```

I want if the value of `baz` is 1, to save the entity in the table `foo1`, and if the value of `baz` is 2, to save in the table `foo2`. Where can I select in which table it would save ?

Comment: Can you explain us what you are trying to achieve? Maybe than we can give you a hint.

Comment: Thank you for your interest ! Actually, I have a lot of entries daily for this entity `foo`, so I want to divide them into multiple tables. For example, I would store the information used oftenly in first table, and the information used not so oftenly in the second table. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't see the benefit. If you have to differ between the entries of `foo1` and `foo2`, but it's the same entity, why don't you save the `baz` property and use it in your query?

Comment: Because I have to much entries for only one table, and I want to divide the size, by saving in two smaller tables.

Comment: My case is much more complex, in the question I just simplified my problem into a trivial example, to be easier to undestand. This is why I have only 2 properties.

Comment: Well I think it's not easy to accomplish this. But maybe you can intercept the persist event, change the mapping "on the fly" (change the table name) based on your value.

Answer (score 3):

Use doctrine inheritance:

[Doctrine inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

It works like this:

BaseClient

- SubClient1 extends from BaseClient
- SubClient2 extends from BaseClient

Like that you can even add extra fields to let's say SubClient1 or SubClient2 who are specific only for that entity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need your $baz attribute ? and how do you determine it?

Because a simple solution that might help you is to make an abstract foo class, and then 2 classes that inherit from it and that do the database's relation.

Here is the example :

```
abstract class foo {

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  */      
  protected $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="string")
 */
 protected $bar;
}


/* @ORM\Table(name="foo1")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="yourRepo")
*/
foo1 extends foo{
}

/* @ORM\Table(name="foo2")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="yourRepo")
*/
foo2 extends foo{
}
```

Though I'm not sure it works as simply as this but maybe it could help.

Some documentation that might help doing this : 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Please feel free to edit/correct, I'm pretty new in this but I think the idea might help .

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, I can't use this solution, because I don't have only two "tables". I presented only two in my question to be easier to understand, but there can be 10, from `foo1` to `foo10`.

Comment: Ok then you might go with a "hack" as suggested by Gremo in last comment, documentations that might help to do so : 
http://symfony2.ylly.fr/dynamically-add-mapping-to-doctrine2-using-annotations-dantleech/
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html#1354-1382